# Library to identifying the similarity between 2 image in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, similarity

Suggestions on the best (preferably easiest way) to compare two images in android.
The first image is in my SD Card.
The second image was taken using Camera in android.

How to measure percentage similarity between those 2 images??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409282/compare-two-images-is-same-or-not May help you.

Comment: if you talking about face matching then i can suggest you

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask specific programming questions. What have you tried? What doesn't work? Please refer to the [faq section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on more information about which questions should be asked here and which shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not provide any picture comparison algorithms for you.

Therefore, you will need to write one yourself - one that fits your needs, since not all image comparison algorithms/techniques are the same, and some work better in some cases than others.

You might want to start by looking at the [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) technique, and find an image matching algorithm that suits your requirements.