# How can i compare two image to know if they have same part

Tags: java, android, image, compare

I have two images - A,B. I need to know in java code if B is a part of A.

PS: Someone told me to handle this with "Reverse Image Search" but I do not know how.

Comment: probably similar question of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999920/looking-for-an-image-comparison-pattern-recognition-library

Comment: Also since you are new, you may want to read [the faq's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)...

Answer (score 0):

Image can be defined as an abstraction of BufferedImage, it just holds header-like information. Before reading the image pixels, compare the images with their sizes.
[Follow me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409282/compare-two-images-is-same-or-not)